# TimePickerDialog not recognizing onTimeSet

Tags: java, android

I'm working on implementing a TimePickerDialog that displays on a button press. I've followed the Android documentation found at [Android Dev Topic](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html) and i've placed the TimePicker class inside of the class from which I want to create the dialog. However, for some reason, when I set the modifier static, I get a "modifier not allowed here" error. When I don't have the class as static, I get a "class must be declared abstract or implement onTimeSet (which I am). Below is my code:

```
public class TimePicker extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
            DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}

public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    // Do something with the time chosen by the user
}
}
```

I've also tried adding @Override before onTimeSet, but I get a message about it not overriding the method from its superclass.

Comment: just remove the onTimeSet method and than override it from the warning shows over the TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener to override the onTimeSet. It's some times happen.

Comment: I've actually found the issue. onTimeSet needed parameters (android.widget.TimePicker view, int one, int two) instead of just Timepicker view